# how to concatenate javascript and rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my application.erb.html `$alertdiv.text("some message");` but I need to pass in message instead of hard coded message. I need to pass in the notice so I tried doing something like `$alertdiv.text(<%= notice %>);` but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to wrap the `<%= %>` tags in quotation marks:

```
$alertdiv.text("<%= notice %>");
```